# How can I store selected values and have the the fields populated upon refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using [select2 jQuery plugin](https://select2.github.io/) to have the multiple selections displayed.

The fields are populates via AJAX and they are displayed dynamically.

I need to find a way somehow to save this data, either via `localStorage` or some other way, so the fields can be populated automatically upon user refresh.

So, the logic should save the selection and populate the field according to the previous selection when user navigates back to that page.

What is the best way to achieve this?

This is the part of html, generated by the plugin:

```
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
    <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
        <input class="select2-search__field" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;" type="search">      
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you extract your AJAX response and place it into the field(s), just also persist it to localStorage:

```
 localStorage.setItem("fieldName", value);
```

And, when the page loads, restore the data:

```
 referenceToTheField.value = localStorage.getItem("fieldName");
```